# Comma instead of period

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting the following errors:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> System.Exception: Unknown error : There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

This is easily seen by what the INSERT statement is:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Out] ([Tag],[Element],[PeriodID],[Pay],[Output Value],[User],[Source],[Date],[ElementID]) values (1014758,'System-Rate Total',153640061,'No',21,67,'z8310905','CalcEngine',getdate(),6859)
```

The problem lies with <21,67> which should be <21.67>

The INSERT statement above gets created in C# like this:

```
 commandText.AppendLine(string.Format("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Out] ([Tag],[Element],[PeriodID],[Pay],[Output Value],[User],[Source],[Date],[ElementID]) values ({0},'{1}',{2},'No',{3},'{4}','CalcEngine',getdate(),{5})", Tag, tx.ElementName, periodID, tx.Value, user, tx.ElementID));
```

So it is tx.Value that contains the comma instead of the period (full stop).

However, this runs fine on my laptop, but not on the server on which we are trying to install the solution. My laptop has Windows 7, the server has Windows 8. This solution uses .Net Framework 4, and VS 2010 was used to create it.

I have tried to set the server culture, language etc in the control panel exactly similar to my laptop's.
I have even added the following to the code to try to stop a similar thing from happening with subsequent installations (for background look [here](http://blog.rastating.com/setting-default-currentculture-in-all-versions-of-net/)):

```
 // Creating a Global culture specific to our application.
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-ZA");

        // Creating the DateTime Information specific to our application.
        System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dateTimeInfo = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
        // Defining various date and time formats.            
        dateTimeInfo.LongDatePattern = "dd MMMM yyyy";
        dateTimeInfo.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
        dateTimeInfo.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss";
        dateTimeInfo.ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm";
        // Setting application wide date time format.
        cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat = dateTimeInfo;

        //Creating the Number Format Information specific to our application.
        System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numberInfo = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();
        numberInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
        // Setting application wide number format.
        cultureInfo.NumberFormat = numberInfo;

        // Assigning our custom Culture to the application.
        CultureChanges.SetDefaultCulture(cultureInfo);
```

This is entered in the Main method of a Windows Service, which starts another process that eventually executes the abovementioned INSERT statement.
(Not sure whether I need to add it to the spawned process as well?)

Anyways, I don't know what more to do or where to go hunting for this error. I guess it must be something with the culture or different set-up of the server. This value of 21.67 is probably rounded.

Comment: Why save it as a string _at all_? Even if not a double, parse it to double first then inser _that_ value and change your column type to mapped double type. You should always choose the right data type for your values. Read: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: Can `{3:##0.00}` solve it? ;).

Comment: Can you add .Replace(',','.') to your variable in the string format?

Comment: Never concatenate sql like this. Use parameteriezed queries or better yet, stored procedures.

Comment: @ Soner Gönül, @Zohar Peled, I agree with you. There are definitely better ways to writing SQL. However, the above statement is one of hundreds of other statements that get executed in a block. In most of the rest of our solution we use LinqToSQL, but we can't hit the DB for every single insert. There are thousands of items that each have hundreds of these inserts. That said, let's try to move on. Why does this work from my laptop, and not from the server?

Comment: It could be a number of things. it's impossible to know without checked every possibility. However, you can simply use `string.replace` to change the comma to a period and be done with it.

Comment: @shA.t, those are possible ways of manipulating the code. However, I would prefer to find the underlying problem. Why does this work from my laptop, but not from the server?

Comment: @JustinThyme is this oracle or other? If oracle, different oracle client versions, or different localization configurations may cause this. If other db, if you haven't yet, you should check the regional settings of both PC's for possible differences.

Comment: @Oğuz Sezer, this is Microsoft SQL Server. Yes, as mentioned in the original post, I have checked the regional settings of both my laptop and the server. Please also look at the code that I showed in the original post to get an idea of what I have tried to set regarding the regional settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the culture I was setting programmatically, as shown in the code block in the original post, was not getting to the individual threads. Thus, when I inserted that code at the place where the threads were started, the correct culture was being picked up for each thread.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing textbox value declare variable double or float and assign that textbox value to variable and pass that variable to insert query

```
double Pay;
Pay=Double.Parse(tx.value)
```

pass this pay to insert query

Comment: There isn't a textbox in the code. tx.value comes from a list object List<TransactionValue<T>>, T being double in this case. This is similar to shA.t and kidshaw's comments above. I would prefer something that addresses the root problem. Remember, this works on my laptop, why not on the server?